# Compute gradient for a function from $H^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If have the function $$I:H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)\to \mathbb{R},~I(u)=\frac12\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u|^2~dx-\frac{\mu}{p}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u|^p~dx,$$ where $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)=W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is the Sobolev space for $2\leq N\leq 4$ and $2<p<2^*$ where $2^*$ is the Sobolev critical exponent ($2^*=\infty$ for $N=1,2$ and $2^*=\frac{2N}{N-2}$ for $N\geq 3$).

I'd like to compute the $H^1$-gradient $\nabla I(u)$, which means that $v:=\nabla I(u)\in H^1$ is given by Riesz repesentation theorem, such that $$dI(u)[\phi]=\langle v,\phi\rangle_{H^1}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}v\phi~dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\nabla v\cdot\nabla \phi~dx.$$

. I computed $$dI(u)[\phi]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\nabla u\cdot\nabla\phi~dx-\mu\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u|^{p-2}u\phi~dx,
$$
but how do I get $v$ now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $u$ you have to solve the variational problem
$$
dI(u)[\phi]=\langle v,\phi\rangle \quad \forall \phi\in H^1
$$
which boils down to solve the pde
$$
-\Delta v + v = -\Delta u + \mu u |u|^{p-2}
$$
for $v$.